# Where can I run SQL?

Tags: sql, xampp, ide

I'm learning SQL on sololearn, and I want to know where I can run SQL?
Does VSC let you run SQL and does it need validation to do so? I have Xampp Installed so if Xampp helps any knowledge would help.
I'm still new to stackoverflow so sorry for wrong questions and stuff like that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few pointers from my experience.

**BigQuery**
You'll need a google account and to setup a billing profile but you won't be charged during the trial, and it's a pretty generous trial in my opinion and I used it at work for 3 solid months without paying a dime. There're plenty of free public datasets you can access and play around with, and you can easily import data via CSV or google sheets and a few other methods if you have your own data you want to practice on.

**StrataScratch**
This site helped me tremendously when learning SQL, and absolutely fantastic once you've learned the basics of SQL. The site provides plenty of questions you must answer relying on SQL to query the datasets provided. This is all possible on the site which is great, so no need to download software or import data, just click a question and go! You can also see other users submissions to the question so you can learn perhaps more efficient ways of getting to the answer.

**MySQL**
Takes a bit of setup initially (compared to bigquery anyway), but once you're done you can use this as your playground for all things SQL related. More Details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/).

For VSC to work as your interface for SQL, you need to connect VSC to a SQL server. I've not done this myself but more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-vscode#:%7E:text=In%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%2C%20press,the%20new%20profile%27s%20connection%20properties.).

Hope this helps!
Tom

Comment: Thank you soo much!! This will help me get started with SQL! Thanks!!